# JavaFX / FXML: Vertical button alongside the entire window

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm using a GridPane as the main scene of my stage, the layout is entirely defined in an FXML file. I want to have a button accross the entire side of the window (i.e. accross all rows of my GridPane), as follows:

[image]

However I just can't get it to work. More precisely, it seems the button just won't strecht accross the entire height. I've set `GridPane.vgrow=ALWAYS`, `maxHeight="Infinity"`, and `GridPane.fillHeight=true` for the button, but still the button is just as long as the text in it, and placed in the center of the side.

How can I get the button to stretch across the entire GridPane? As mentioned in the beginning, of course I've set the `GridPane.rowSpan` correctly. It's not that the button is not placed correctly in the GridPane, it's just that it won't strecht itself accross the entire available vertical space.

And please note I would prefer a solution via FXML, not Java code, because I wouldn't want to have such layouting code in my classes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to do this would be to use css. Follow the following steps:

To rotate the label used in the button, use :

```
.button > .text {
    -fx-rotate: 90;
}
```

For extending the button to use the entire height, use Infinity as preferred height :

```
.button {
    -fx-pref-height: Infinity;
    -fx-pref-width: 75;
}
```

**MCVE**

Here is an example, which shows how to use the above code :

FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<GridPane styleClass="root" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="50.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="50.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.rowSpan="3" />
      <VBox style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <VBox style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <VBox style="-fx-background-color: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

CSS

`root` is the style-class assigned to GridPane.

```
.root {
    -fx-background-color: grey;
    -fx-hgap: 5;
    -fx-vgap: 5;
    -fx-padding: 5;
}

.root > .button > .text {
    -fx-rotate: 90;
}

.button {
    -fx-pref-height: Infinity;
    -fx-pref-width: 75;
}
```

Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/grid.fxml"));
        final Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 685, 411);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/grid.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it is a good question man. it was hard to figure out to do it but here the result and FXML file that scene builder make to do this :

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<GridPane hgap="20.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" vgap="5.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="NEVER" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="500.0" prefWidth="500.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
      <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <AnchorPane GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowSpan="3" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Button contentDisplay="TOP" mnemonicParsing="false" textOverrun="CLIP" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
               <font>
                  <Font size="11.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <Label minWidth="-Infinity" rotate="90.0" text="Some Text">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Here what i have done:
I put Gridepane as parent for other controller , it contain 2 column and 3 row for example ,then i put anchor pane and index (0,0) and make column span to remain and put other component as you want in other rows, then i but button in anchor pane and set value of anchor pane constrain to 0 for all corner (you can find anchor pane constrain under layout section of button) after that I delete the text of the button and put label with text in button , finally i rotated the label 90 degree (you can find rotate property under transformation at layout of label) and then you got what you want .

i hope that i answer to your question!

Comment: hi ali, thanks for your effort. but this looks quite hacked, and the code doesn't really make much sense to me. There has to be a simpler, cleaner solution to this.

Comment: how it look hacked?
every thing i make like you want and it is resizable as you want !!!!

Comment: I want to understand how to set this up, not use generated code. Can you explain to me why all this is required, like mnemonicParsing=false and textOverrun=CLIP? and all the minWidth and maxWidth settings seem to not really make sense too. It just seems to me that this is not the best solution

Comment: i explained how to do it manually in java code , or you can use scene builder to generate fxml file like that

Answer (score 0):

**Select the Vertical Button**.

In `SceneViewer` go to Layout Drop Down.

1.Set **minHeight,minWidth,prefWidth,prefHeight,MaxWidth**

```
            to 
   **USE_COMPUTED_SIZE**
```

and **maxHeight**

```
            to
      **MAX_VALUE**
```

2.The `Button` has to span all the rows of GridPane.

3.The `Button` has to be rotated by 90 degree

Note also something important here.When you resize a column or row in SceneViewer the size you set will be the maximum size.

This might add problems cause if the window grows the GridPane will not go accordingly.

So select all the columns  and rows and be soore that the max size is set to

**USE_COMPUTED_SIZE** if you want them to grow.I added this just as advice.

Comment: sorry, I'm not looking for an explanation what to do in the GUI builder. I want a technical explanation what code to write manually (I hate auto-generated code)

Comment: You can use SceneBuilder and then study the fxml produced.Thats the purpose of SceneBuilder.I used to write it manually but when you can have the Lamborgini you don't take the 400$car.